# Setting Cross-origin-Embedder-Policy and Cross-origin-Opener-Policy headers in Express

Tags: javascript, express, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I've been developing a website using Express for the backend and React for the frontend. I've come across the issue where my application won't work on Firefox due to this error: 'ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined.' After searching a bit online, it appears to be related to CORS. I also noticed that Chrome issues a warning about the use of SharedArrayBuffer.

So, I read that I need to set these headers: `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` and `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp`.

But I am not sure how to do that. On my backend, I've been using the 'cors' package to set my CORS headers and options like this:

```
const corsMiddleware = cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: allowedCorsOrigins
});
app.use(corsMiddleware);

app.options('*', corsMiddleware);
```

I've also tried using this method, but it doesn't appear to work either:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin');
  res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp');
  next();
});
```

Am I totally missing something or misunderstanding? It is my first time developing a web application, and I am kind of lost at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"I've also tried using this method, but it doesn't appear to work either"_. What you mean? Are the headers set on the response received by the browser?

Comment: Does `res.set()` instead of `res.setHeader()` work? Where do you add this middleware?

Comment: I attempted to manually set the headers using the provided code, but it didn't work as expected. I'm currently exploring alternative solutions to ensure the correct inclusion of CORS headers in the response. I haven't tried `res.set()`, but I will give it a shot. Also, I added this middleware in the `server.js` file.

Comment: You also need a [secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts). Which means serving the website over https. For local development serving from localhost over http is also acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, @rveerd. `res.set()` didn't work, but somehow (I don't know how), `res.setHeader()` did. However, there's a catch: when I add that code to `server.js`, I get a `Localhost refused to connect` error. Additionally, when I open the console inside the inspect, I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at HTMLDocument.onDocumentLoad (VM30164:627:19)
onDocumentLoad @ VM30164:627
`
This VM30164 file is browser-generated.